# Efficient way to get unique value from log file

Tags: shell, awk

There is a large log file of 10GB, and formatted as following:

```
node123`1493000000`POST /api/info`app_id=123&token=123&sign=abc
node456`1493000000`POST /api/info`app_id=456&token=456&sign=abc
node456`1493000000`POST /api/info`token=456&app_id=456&sign=abc
node456`1493000000`POST /api/info`token=456&sign=abc&app_id=456
```

Now I want to get unique app_ids from the log file. For example, the expected result of the log file above should be:

```
123
456
```

I do that with shell script `awk -F 'app_id=' '{print $2}' $filename | awk -F '&' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq`, and is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Do you mean just getting `app_id=123` or the entire line that contains `app_id`?

Comment: Your example is terrible, You want unique output but don't show any dups in the target input values and you use the same values multiple times on each line. The net result is we can run a script against your sample input that is completely wrong and it'd produce the same output as a script that was correct and in the end you didn't show us any expected output at all so it's all just guess work anyway! Read [ask] and then try again with  a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If your log file's name is  log_file.txt,you can use these commands:

1. `grep -Po "(?<=&app_id=)[0-9]+" log_file.txt`
2. `awk -F "[&=]" '{print $4}' log_file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Change the logfile name

```
    awk '{print $17" "$18" "$19" "$20}' log.txt |sort -k1|uniq  >> z #apache
    # filename on line number(0-9) awk result
    while read x;
    do
    echo $x
    grep "$x" log.txt | wc -l 
    done < z
```